# MS SQL server runs slowly on new Linux server

Tags: sql-server, linux, ms-access

I am running a relatively small Access application with an SQL server 2019 backend, and have recently updated my ~10+yr old Linux system that is running the server.  I was surprised to find that SQL server actually runs noticeably slower on the new system.  Here is a comparison of the two systems:[System comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkVe4.png).

By every measure the new system is substantially faster, but for comparison a particularly intensive pass-through query completes in about 2 sec on the old system and 7-10 sec on the new system.

I initially thought that it must be due to using Docker on the new system, since SQL server isn’t yet compatible with Ubuntu 22.04, but I recreated the Docker container on the old system and saw the same speeds.  As I’m on Linux, I don’t have access to SSMS and the performance tools. I have reviewed [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-performance-best-practices?view=sql-server-ver16) MS guidelines but there are too many things to troubleshoot individually, and I’m not a DB admin, this is just a small application for a few users.

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot or what the potential issues could be would be much appreciated.  Just to be clear, I’m not interested in optimizing the query, just determining why it is running slower on the much faster system.

Comment: Have you compared the execution plans of a problem query on the old/new SQL instance?

Comment: Why did you add the `vba` and `ms-access` tags?

Comment: `I don’t have access to SSMS and the performance tools.` you do. You can run SSMS on a remote machine. The performance tools are part of SQL Server, not SSMS. SSMS only provides the nice GUI. You can also use Azure Data Studio and its own tools. Finally, you can always use scripts like Brent Ozar's First Responder Kit to not only gather the same information but also identify the problems.

Comment: Azure Data Studio comes with built-in dashboards and allows you to create your own. Check for example [Tutorial: Add the five slowest queries sample widget to the database dashboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/tutorial-qds-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added the vba and ms-access tags as the front-end is written with that, but may not be relevant.  I should clarify that using SSMS is not an option due to restrictions on my Windows work computer/network. Thanks for pointing out Azure Data Studio, I wasn't aware of it, or the scripts.  It looks like it has a Linux version, so will try it out.

Comment: "*suggestions on how to troubleshoot...Just to be clear, I’m not interested in optimizing the query.*" - Bit of an oxymoron because most likely the query is the source of the problem. This is a common occurrence with databases where the same query doesn't execute in the same manner between two systems (even when the systems are built near-identically). The general *why* is too long for a comment but it basically has to do with how the database engine comes up with a plan it thinks is best to run the query, which is a complex task. Posting the execution plan from both systems is how to proceed.

Comment: I compared the execution plans from each system in Azure Data Studio, and they do indeed differ.  I'm not sure why exactly, as everything is identical in terms of the databases, queries, indexes, etc., except for the system's themselves.

Comment: After a bit of digging I found that the amount of parallelism can take a hit on the query.  The new system has 56 cores, while the old system only 8.  I found setting the 'max degree of parallelism' to 1 (ie. use only 1 cpu) actually resulted in the best performance, counterintuitively.  I was able to excute in 1.672s, instead of 2.519s on the old system - not a big improvement considering the much better hardware but at least not worse.  Too bad sql server can't make better use of the extra cpus.